# Docker + .Net core persist static files

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

So I containerized my .net core project using docker and docker-compose. After building and running docker-compose up, everything works just fine. after uploading a file via api, It uploads the file inside the docker container as I ran docker exec -it  bash and cd into the StaticFiles directory, the file was there and when retrieving it from and api, it worked as expected.
Then I ran the docker volume ls and this is the result:

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     buildx_buildkit_default_state
local     fiber_SqlDataBase
local     fiber_StaticFilesBackend
```

then docker volume inspect fiber_StaticFilesBackend:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-01-31T05:52:39Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "fiber",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.20.3",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "StaticFilesBackend"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/fiber_StaticFilesBackend/_data",
        "Name": "fiber_StaticFilesBackend",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

so I cd into the Mountpoint and found out that there was no file inside the _data directory.
I want to persist the files on my Linux machine so every time building the docker-compose wouldn't delete the static files.

also this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  
  fiber-sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU10-ubuntu-22.04
    container_name: Fiber-SQL-DB
    networks:
        - backend
    ports:
        - "32788:1433"
    environment:
       SA_PASSWORD: "MyPassword"
       ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    volumes:
        - SqlDataBase:/var/opt/mssql

    restart: unless-stopped


  webfiber:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webfiber
    container_name: BackendFiber
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebFiber/Dockerfile
    networks: 
        - backend
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    environment:
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:80"
        ASPNET_VERSION: "7.0.3"
        DOTNET_VERSION: "7.0.3"
    volumes:
       - StaticFilesBackend:/var/opt/Fiber

    restart: unless-stopped
    
  seq:
    image: datalust/seq:latest
    container_name: fiber.seq
    networks:
        - backend
    environment:
       ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
        - 5341:5341
        - 8081:80
    
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  SqlDataBase:
  StaticFilesBackend:
```

and the project docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebFiber/WebFiber.csproj", "WebFiber/"]
COPY ["ApplicationFiber/ApplicationFiber.csproj", "ApplicationFiber/"]
COPY ["CoreLayer/CoreLayer.csproj", "CoreLayer/"]
COPY ["DomainFiber/DomainFiber.csproj", "DomainFiber/"]
COPY ["Utils/Utils.csproj", "Utils/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebFiber/WebFiber.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebFiber"
RUN dotnet build "WebFiber.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebFiber.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebFiber.dll"]
```

first I though that building docker-file would modify the directory as it's copying the StaticFiles folder that does not contain any data in it.
But then I realized that the files are not even being stored on the linux machine.

Comment: If I am asking, means I really need your help. voting -1 would lead to closing it so I will stay confused. at least tell me what am I doing wrong then vote that. Thanks

Comment: Your application code usually shouldn't be in volumes at all.  If `dotnet publish` preserves the static assets, they'll be in the image.  Does your application work if you delete the `volumes:` block under `webfiber`?

Comment: Yes, before trying to save StaticFiles, there was no volumes inside the docker container. but after this problem in which I saw the files were being lost each time after building docker compose, I decided to add volumes which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by modifying the Docker-compose file like this:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  
  fiber-sql-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU10-ubuntu-22.04
    container_name: Fiber-SQL-DB
    networks:
        - backend
    ports:
        - "32788:1433"
    environment:
       SA_PASSWORD: "MyPass"
       ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    volumes:
        - SqlDataBase:/var/opt/mssql

    restart: unless-stopped


  webfiber:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webfiber
    container_name: BackendFiber
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebFiber/Dockerfile
    networks: 
        - backend
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    environment:
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: "http://+:80"
        ASPNET_VERSION: "7.0.3"
        DOTNET_VERSION: "7.0.3"
    volumes:
       - /home/ubuntu/Docker/StaticFiles:/app/StaticFiles

    restart: unless-stopped
    
  seq:
    image: datalust/seq:latest
    container_name: fiber.seq
    networks:
        - backend
    environment:
       ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
        - 5341:5341
        - 8081:80
    
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  SqlDataBase:
```

I created a StaticFiles directory inside /home/ubuntu/Docker/ of my linux host, then by adding this line:

```
 - /home/ubuntu/Docker/StaticFiles:/app/StaticFiles
```

as volumes, now it's persisting my files even after I rebuild the
docker-compose. Before I was just creating a volume for my whole
project which actually meant nothing.

Hope this helps.